# Video player for Raspberry Pi 1/2/3/4

Tags: raspbian, omxplayer

My project, unfortunately, was affected by the release of the raspberry 4 and buster. My script shows on my clients' tv advertising videos with subtitles resized and positioned ad hoc and with a fixed 720p resolution for any type of TV.

The command it executes is:

```
omxplayer --display=5 -o hdmi --win "0 0 1280 720" --layer 2 --blank --vol -80 --no-ghost-box --align center --font-size 45 --font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSansBold.ttf --no-keys video.mp4
```

For now, the omxplayer distribution for buster has bugs and subtitles are disabled. In fact, running the command with Raspberry pi 4 shows this error:

```
omxplayer.bin: OMXPlayerSubtitles.h: 86: bool OMXPlayerSubtitles :: GetUseExternalSubtitles (): Assertion `m_open 'failed.
```

There is no way to solve it for now. So since some of my customers have already purchased the RPi4 I find myself with this headache.

These are the questions:

1) Which player can I use that works with the same command line on both RPi123 and RPi4, Raspian Stretch/Buster?

2) And what is its syntax to achieve the same result as the command with omxplayer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The media file had a subtitle file with the same name up to the extension.

I made a new directory and created a symlink to the media file only, then played the symlink and it worked without issue.

Weird stuff

Comment: Did Omxplayer work by showing the subtitles correctly or just playing the video?